# Mac: replace text inside files in directory using regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, terminal

I need to replace all matches (regular expression) in directory from "*::" to be "\*::"
examples: (in multiple php files)

```
ID::
user::
process::

....
```

to be:

```
\ID::
\user::
\process::
```

I currently use,single commands

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '' s/ID::/\\\\ID::/ {} +
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '' s/user::/\\\\user::/ {} +
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '' s/process::/\\\\process::/ {} +
```

how to write regular expression to replace any "*::" => "\*::"

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update "bebop" solution to meet my requirements, alot of thanks to him

solution:

```
sed -i -e 's/\([A-Za-z]*\)::/\\\1::/g' `grep -ril '::' *.php`
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use "grouping" or "back-referencing" to refer back to a portion of the regular expression. This is done by surrounding the intended group with `\(` and `\)`, and referring back to them with `\1`, `\2`, etc. In your case, the following expression should work:

```
$ echo -e "ID::\nuser::\nprocess::" | sed 's/\(.*\)::/\\\1::/g'
```

with the following output:

```
\ID::
\user::
\process::
```

Comment: I need to replace any pattern end with "::" to be "\ * ::", I don't want to spacifiy "ID", "user" or "process" classes

Comment: I don't have full list of classes names (that need to replace)

Comment: @mwafi The only important part of my example is the sed part, and it will work for any string that is captured by `.*`

Comment: I tried: $ find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed 's/\(.*\)::/\\\1::/g' {} +     (no effects on files)

Comment: try: `sed -i -e 's/\(.*\)::/\\\1::/g' \`grep -ril '::' *.php\``

Comment: thanks for help, it convert  `$date = DB::` to `\ $date = DB::`